# Bluetooth does not output sound to wireless headphones

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth

am new to linux, I have ubunto 20.4 and i have problem with bluetooth. I have wireless headphones, I manage to link them to bluetooth but then it doesn't output sound. Someone could help me? Thank you so much.

As I am new to this, I have been looking for a solution to my problem on the internet, I have tried something else but I have not been able to solve my problem. Sorry for being so basic but I'm totally new.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What result from terminal for `pactl list short | grep -i blue`

Comment: when i write in terminal pactl list short | grep -i blue nothing comes up

Comment: Try `sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` reboot